# Typescript types problem with Google Maps LatLng{}

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, typescript-types

I'm creating a Typescript app that takes an address from the user and displays it on a Google map.

I've created a `type GoogleGeocodingResponse` that accepts the GeoCoding `response.data.results` as `{geometry: {location: {lat: Number; lng: Number}}}`

Then I use Axios to:

```js
.get<GoogleGeocodingResponse>(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? 
   address=${encodeURI(enteredAddress)}&key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}`
 )
```

The part I don't get is, how can I use this data to create a `LatLng`?  I've been using:

```js
const coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng({
  lat: Number(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat),
  lng: Number(response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng),
})
```

Casting to type `Number` works, but it seems I should be able to get the data directly from the `GoogleGeocodingResponse` without having to cast first.  Do I have to specifically define a type?  Is there a type in `@types/google.maps` I can use? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mix the type `Number` with `number`.

> Type `Number` is not assignable to type `number`. `number` is a primitive, but `Number` is a wrapper object. Prefer using `number` when possible.

`{geometry: {location: {lat: number; lng: number}}}` (`N` -> `n`)

I have tested it. It works. You should always use the primitive types (lowercase). No cast necessary anymore. You could also just use `as number` behind your assignment if you want. But I recommend to change your type from `Number` to `number`.

**Solution A (recommended):**

```
// Use primitive types.
type YourType = { geometry: { location: { lat: number; lng: number } } };
```

**Solution B:**

```
const coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng({
  lat: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat as number,
  lng: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng as number,
})
```

Btw. your solution of `Number(value)` only works because `Number` returns the type `number` (primitive / lowercase).

Read more of [TypeScript Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html).

> ❌ Don’t ever use the types Number, String, Boolean, Symbol, or Object These types refer to non-primitive boxed objects that are almost never used appropriately in JavaScript code.

> ✅ Do use the types number, string, boolean, and symbol.

Comment: Yep, exactly right @Dominik.  I typed "YourType" wrong in the first place and got confused by the "Number v. number" error messages it returned.  Thanks!